# How do you push Android Instrumentation Tests to Emulator/Device?

Tags: android, webkit

I'm trying to run the Webkit Layout Tests on the Android emulator using the command line shell in Ubuntu 9.04.

`adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w \
com.android.dumprendertree/com.android.dumprendertree.LayoutTestsAutoRunner`

I get this error:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.android.dumprendertree/com.android.dumprendertree.LayoutTestsAutoRunner}
```

I found that you need to use development/testrunner/runtest.py to push tests in android/frameworks/base/tests.

I've tried this to push the AndroidTests:

`. ./build/envsetup.sh
 emulator&
./development/testrunner/runtest.py android`

But it gives me this error:

```
Error: ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT not defined. Please run envsetup.sh
```

I did run envsetup.sh! Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Where can I find envsetup.sh? It gives me no such file or directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer at [Android - Instrumentation Testing](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/instrumentation_testing.html)

`. build/envsetup.sh
(cd frameworks/base/tests/DumpRenderTree/ && mm) && \
adb install out/target/product/generic/data/app/DumpRenderTree.apk`

Then you can run the instrumentation tests:

`adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument -w \
com.android.dumprendertree/com.android.dumprendertree.LayoutTestsAutoRunner`

Answer (score 0):

once you launch adb shell in command line:

go with a command stating the package(com.ni.Keyboard) say of Keyboard application..

## am instrument -w com.ni.Keyboard.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner