# Running DumpRenderTree on an Android device

Tags: android

I have been trying to run the DumpRenderTree test in Android (on my Android device running ICS) and am unable to figure out how to run it. There is very little documentation and the only other thread I found (that is close to my question) is this:

[How do you push Android Instrumentation Tests to Emulator/Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520503/how-do-you-push-android-instrumentation-tests-to-emulator-device)

Here is my ddms output when I run this command:

```
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253): started: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253): failed: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253): ----- begin exception -----
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.android.dumprendertree.LayoutTestsAutoTest
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:263)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
05-23 11:59:07.118: INFO/TestRunner(10253): ----- end exception -----
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): finished: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): started: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): failed: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): ----- begin exception -----
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.android.dumprendertree.LoadTestsAutoTest
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:263)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:537)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253):     at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): ----- end exception -----
05-23 11:59:07.126: INFO/TestRunner(10253): finished: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1)
```

Should I be pushing in some tests before I run this? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way to show the render tree is by inputting **`about:debug.render.file`** in the URL bar of the stock android browser.

Then you can find a file generated at **`/mnt/sdcard/renderTree.txt`**.

Similarly, **`about:debug.dom.file`** results in a DOM tree output.

Comment: Sadly they took this out of the new WebView for 4.4